# How to find out currently logged in users in Rails 2.3.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does any one know solution to tracking online users in Rails; when you have cookie based sessions? I am using Rails 2.3.5. If yes please let me know.

Thanks, Atul

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said how you're doing authentication, but I'm guessing that you have a controller that creates a session when a user logs in and destroys it when they log out again. You could have those actions also add and remove (respectively) a record from a database table to enable you to track each user.

Comment: Hi John,

  Thanks for the reply. We are using Restful authentication. Well yes we can implement your solution; issue is sessions are cookie based so what if user does not logs out explicitly? we can write a work around for that as well i.e a default session expiry time for inactive users. But what I am looking for is a plugin which will do this in a more cleaner way. Is there any plugin for this?  I Googled but couldnt find any. Please let me know if you know any plugin which can handle this.I am checking if restful-auth had this feature. 

Thanks in advance.
Atul.

Comment: @Autl Sorry, I'm not aware of any plugin that does this.

Comment: Np, thanks for your help. Will update this thread once I find out a solution to this.

Thanks,
Atul